# Set height : 'auto' in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i was looking for a way to set the height of an image auto but turn the autoscale off cause when i click on an image at the first time it show half of it but when close and click it once again shows image truly. is there any way to set height auto? here's the code.

```
$("a#example2").fancybox({
                    'autoDimensions': false,
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'width': 650,
                    'height': 650,
                    'overlayShow': true,
                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut': 'elastic'
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images, `width` and `height` have not effect (neither does `autoDimensions`). Images are displayed either "auto-scaled"  to fit in the viewport (when `autoScale` is set to `true`) or in their original size (when `autoScale` is set to `false`).

If the height of the image is higher than the viewport and `autoScale` has been set to `false`, you might scroll down the page to see the full image.

In your case, make sure you are wrapping your fancybox script inside the `ready()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a#example2").fancybox({
  'autoScale': false,
  'overlayShow': true,
  'transitionIn': 'elastic',
  'transitionOut': 'elastic'
 });
});
```

You may also try adding the option `"type": "image"` in case your link looks like `href="domain.com/path/image/?=4635"` or it doesn't have an image extension (jpg,png,gif)